# Using jar libraries with Jboss and Openshift

Tags: jboss7.x, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a simple REST Webservice on Openshift, using Jboss and Eclipse.
I have a Jar library cointaining some classes, I put that in the path:

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/

of the project. Deploying the application locally and testing it is ok, but when I try to deploy on Openshift I get an error at build time:

ClassNotFoundException

Reading the log I noticed that Jboss (on Openshift) doesn't find my Jar: why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check if library exists in war (you can unzip this file)
- Check if war is deployed in remote server and unzip war to view libraries: ssh 5fcd6........@yourappname-yourdomain.rhcloud.com
- Check path: /var/lib/stickshift/5fcd6......../app-root/runtime/repo/deployments
- View Readme in folder deployments (in local)
- You should use Maven. Sample:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>org.slf4j,org.apache.commons.logging,org.joda.time</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>yourapp</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName><!-- ROOT -->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```